# Google Apps - SPF Softfail when sending to same domain

Tags: email, g-suite, spf

I am using Google Apps to send mail through my private domain. I have used WHM to set my DNS `TXT` record to `"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"` for `mydomain.com.` as [advised by Google](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=178723).

When I send a bunch of SMTP mails, I get SPF passes to emails sent to external domains from `admin@mydomain.com`. But emails that go to `anythingelse@mydomain.com` get a softfail as follows:

```
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning admin@mydomain.com does not designate 123.123.123.123 as permitted sender) client-ip=123.123.123.123;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning admin@mydomain.com does not designate 123.123.123.123 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=admin@mydomain.com
```

where `123.123.123.123` is the dedicated IP for `mydomain.com`.

Any idea why this is? Even though I have set the server to send SMTP through Google, it seems to just overwrite that for emails to the local domain. I have tried changing the `TXT` record to `"v=spf1 ipv4:123.123.123.123 include:_spf.google.com ~all"` but get the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long did you wait after making the change to your SPF record? What is the TXT records TTL? Based on the information you're providing you seem to have it configured correctly. DNS is cached and replicated system so you make take hours or days based on the length of the TTL.

Edit:
I believe you have a **typo** it should be **"ip4:123.123.123.123"** Check that your SPF is vaild here http://www.openspf.org/.